# How to create an entity view with list of related entities in JHipster 3.x?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

New to JHipster, so bear with me :). I'd like to display lists of related entities on an entity detail view. How can I do that? Since this is common in this application, it would be best to have a generic way of doing this instead of modifying each entity (e.g. by modifying the generator), but per entity editing is OK if there is no other way.

An example: I have Courses and each Course may have many Lessons, Students and Clients connected. Now on the Course detail view below the Course fields I'd like to have three lists for each of the related Lessons, Students and Clients (e.g. similar to what SalesForce does).

The question has two sides: how can I get the proper data (serialization), and how can I change the view? The latter (change view) seems to be simple if I do it by hand for each entity, but would be nice to have it generated.

This seems to be a common UX theme. Is there a sample application somewhere covering this use case?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

1) you make your `CourseResource` delievering eager fetched entities of `Course`, which have **no** `@JsonIgnore` over your Set of lessons. In the end, by calling one course, the JSON should contain the related entities.

***in detail (edit)***:

consider, you generated your app with a JDL like this:

```
entity Course {
    courseName String
}

entity Lesson {
    lessonName String
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Course{lesson} to Lesson
}
```

Then first go to `Course` class and change the Set to the following:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//@JsonIgnore - remove this
private Set<Lesson> lessons = new HashSet<>();
```

This is the quickiest way, but not the most perfomant, since everytime you query courses, you join on lessions, too. To avoid that, you must build some @Query into your repository where you manually join to that...but I will keep it simple for now.

The removal of @JsonIgnore will lead to the lessons implicitly being part of your Course representation, so you will got all options to visualize this in the UI

2) find some way to display it, in a way you want

generally I feel it seems to be a good idea of having some generator, but it might be harder than you think. Like, how to represent the data. If you got multiple relationships to that entity, will you use tabs? If tabs, but there is only one relation ship, does the tab still is adequate? Is that more on this, still adequate to decide this in JHipsters central generator, or this should be open for the developer?

I think, it worths a discussion, but nevertheless there could be done some JHipster module to accomplish this

Best Regards

<strike>P.S.: if my answer was to short, ask me on...it's just late and I am lazy to paste down a full blown answer :)</strike>

Comment: Hi David - thx for the kwik rply! Yes, I'd appreciate if you could flash out the first part a bit more :) I see one issue here which is always a problem with APIs: in this particular case (entity detail view) I'd like a compound reply with all the dependencies (up to a certain number of records) so that one round-trip is enough, but sometimes I'd might just want a leaner return with the core Course data.

Comment: (contd.) For the second (display) part: in this case I'd like to display the related items on the same page as separate lists (or simply eliminate them if there are no entries) maybe with a linking to the other detail screens, which is doable, no problem.

Comment: (contd.) Overall: I'm a bit fond of the jhipster-jdl.jh file and this "hyper meta-programming". So actually it would be fun to extend the generator in a way that I actually describe what I need in the .jh file (for example that for which detail screen which related lists should be displayed) and then the code would automatically be generated or the additional DOM nodes would be created during runtime based on the description (more of what I generally do in other frameworks).

Comment: (contd.) And finally I feel that JHipster lacks a collection of simple but very common examples (like this question) that would help people who are new to JHipster to get a feel for the most JHipstery way of doing things - because there are kadzillion ways of doing something, but each framework has its philosophy how it is done best :).

Comment: in first, yes, every framework consists of a couple of philosophy, but a good framework shouldn't decide to much for the user, to leave some freedom to the dev. The more details you provide, the less the target group gets

Comment: Thanks, David! Will have a couple more questions ;)